# std :: is_function on member function?

Tags: c++, function, templates, std

I can do the following to detect if something is a function:

```
void f()
{
}

int main()
{
  std :: cout << std :: is_function <decltype(f)> :: value << std :: endl; // true
}
```

Now, what happens if I want to do the same, but with a function that is a method of a class?

I naively tried to do something like

```
class myclass
{
public:
  void f()
  {
  }
};

int main()
{
  std :: cout << std :: is_function <decltype(myclass :: f)> :: value << std :: endl;
}
```

But I get

```
Call to non-static member function without an object argument
```

What am I supposed to do? I would like something like the above to.. well, to just print `true`.

Comment: That is a truly excessive amount of spacing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A member function pointer is not the same as an ordinary pointer to function. Also, `myclass::f` is ill-formed without an `&`. For member functions there exists [`std::is_member_function_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class myclass
{
public:
   void f() {}
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&myclass::f)>::value << std::endl;
}
```

[Live on ideone](http://ideone.com/dqnEUt)

Answer (score 2):

`decltype(myclass :: f)` is ill-formed.

You can use [`std::is_member_function_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer) (`std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype( &myclass::f )>::value`).

The interesting thing is a possible implementation of `std::is_member_function_pointer` taking advantage of `std::is_function`:

```
template< class T >
struct is_member_function_pointer_helper : std::false_type {};

template< class T, class U>
struct is_member_function_pointer_helper<T U::*> : std::is_function<T> {};

template< class T >
struct is_member_function_pointer : is_member_function_pointer_helper<
                                    typename std::remove_cv<T>::type
                                    > {};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the address - it must be a *pointer* to member function:

```
decltype(&myclass::f)
```

Otherwise, the syntax parses as referencing a static function - hence the error. However, `&myclass::f` is not a function - you can't just call it (`std::is_function` will return `false`).

Answer (score 0):

`myclass::f` is supposed to be function invoking, but the arguments is not provided, which cause the compiler error.

You can use `operator&` to take the address of the member function, such as `&myclass::f`, but it's a member function pointer, [`std::is_function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function) will return `false`.

> Checks whether T is a function type. Types like std::function, lambdas, classes with overloaded operator() and pointers to functions doesn't count as a function type.

You can use [`std::is_member_function_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer) to check whether it's a non-static member function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In C++17 you can use helper function `std::is_member_function_pointer_v`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    int fun() const&;
};


int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&A::fun)> << '\n';
}
```